# Android skydrive username

Tags: android, onedrive

Is there a way to get the skydrive username after a successfull oauth login? I can't find anything in the documentation. I also looked at all the methods of the LiveConnectSession and didn't see it there either.

Answer (score 0):

It is in the json object

```
LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
                LiveOperation operationResult = client.getAsync("me",new LiveOperationListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(LiveOperation arg0) {
                        Log.d(TAG,arg0.getResult().toString());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(LiveOperationException arg0,
                            LiveOperation arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }});
```